# ng-model value is undefind in the dynamically added objects to dom

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, angular-ngmodel

Here is my code
This is static code.
`<label for="lbitemname">Name</label>`
`<input type="text" id="lb-item-name" ng-model="lb.itemname1" />`

These are dynamic, i.e they are added to DOM when I click add button on my page.
`<label for="lbitemname">Name</label>`
`<input type="text" id="lb-item-name" ng-model="lb.itemname2" />`

`<label for="lbitemname">Name</label>`
`<input type="text" id="lb-item-name" ng-model="lb.itemname3" />`

My problem is when I pass these values to controller.
lb.itemname2 and lb.itemname3 are undefined.

Comment: How do you insert the elements into the DOM ? Do you compile them to make them "Angular-aware" ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Yes I have added it into the DOM. But I don't know how to make it angular aware. Please help!! I am new to angularjs.

Comment: I am adding elements using jQuery.

Comment: In order for directives to "take effect" (i.e. to tell Angular that these are Angular-specific stuff and should be hendled accordingly) you need to compile them (using Angular's $compile). If you share some code (where/how you add the elements) I can help more.